# Multiple jQuery events on one element with different functions and target selectors

Tags: jquery, event-handling, live, function-calls

Is there a way to combine these two methods of handling the event attachment in jQuery?

```
$('selector').on({
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {},
    mousedown:  function() {},
    mouseup:    function() {}
});
```

I prefer the previous method but need something like the following to work with "live"-events (the problem is that this will not work if there's a comment between the handlers):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'selector1', function(){})
           .on('mouseleave', 'selector2', function(){})
           .on('mousedown',  'selector3', function(){})
           .on('mouseup',    'selector4', function(){});
```

However, is there a workaround to do it like this?:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: 'selector1': function() {},
    mouseleave: 'selector2': function() {},
    mousedown:  'selector3': function() {},
    mouseup:    'selector4': function() {}
});
```

**Update**

I've ended up with this simple `on`-wrapper function: https://gist.github.com/4191657

The usage is quite simple:

```
$(document).act(
    ['mouseenter', 'selector1', function() {}],
    ['mouseleave', 'selector2', function() {}],
    ['mousedown', 'selector3', function() {}],
    ['mouseup', 'selector4', function() {}]
);
```

Any suggestions or improvements to this?

Comment: Maybe ["mouseenter", "mouseleave"].each()?

Comment: im not sure what your question is as it's possible to do what u wrote, check documentation : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @eric.itzhak take a look at my updated question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the jQuery docs for the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You can pass a selector as the second argument when you use the event map version that you use in your first example:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {},
    mousedown: function() {},
    mouseup: function() {}
}, "selector");
```

This assumes that you want to use the same selector for all of those events. If it can differ, your best option may be to chain the calls to `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'selector1', function(){})
           .on('mouseleave', 'selector2', function(){})
           // ...etc
```

Comment: _and target selector(s)_ I think the OP has different selectors for each event type

Comment: @yckart I've grown pretty fond of this method ( Because I can easily store `$(this)` in a variable at the top. ): http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EUqKN/ and of course you can bloat that with many more events like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/gX2Fj/

Comment: @Joonas Not really what I asked ;)

Comment: @James Allardice 2nd approach is a good way but kills the clarity if the code will be a bit bigger and even if there're comments between the handlers it will break the code...

Comment: @yckart So I may not have read the question properly, or at all... How about his example: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/EUqKN/2/ ( Still didn't read the question... I'm a rebel.. )

Comment: @Joonas a bit over bloated, eh?!

Comment: @Joonas take a look at my updated question, any suggestions to this?

Comment: @yckart When I look at that, I'm having trouble figuring out if it actually improves anything. You might want to throw this in here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @yckart - Why do you want to use that over simple chaining of `.on()` calls? In my opinion it decreases readability.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to improve your wrapper function so that it's possible to use objects instead of arrays when defining events. In similar way how Meteor.js does it.

```
// inspired by https://gist.github.com/yckart/4191657
// This code allows you to use more easy to read syntax to define events in jQuery
// Usage:
// $(document).events({
//  'click, .target-selector': function() {
//      //your function to trigger when target selector is clicked
//  }
// });

;(function($) {
    $.fn.events = function() {
        var argumentsObject = arguments[0];
        return this.each(function() {   
            for (var propertyName in argumentsObject) {
                if (argumentsObject.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                    var argumentsToPass = propertyName.split(", ");
                    argumentsToPass.push(argumentsObject[propertyName]);
                    $(this).on(argumentsToPass[0], argumentsToPass[1], argumentsToPass[2]);
                }
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```