# Jquery On combine

Tags: jquery

I am using these functions which work perfectly:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.profile li', function(e) {
            //Alot of cool code
    });
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.profile li', function(e) {
            //Alot of cool code
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.profile li', function(e) {
            //Alot of cool code
    });
    $(document).on('keydown', '.profile li', function(e) {
            //Alot of cool code
    });
```

but I wanted to combine them into this:

```
    $('.profile li').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
             //Alot of cool code
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
             //Alot of cool code
        },
        click: function (e) {
            //Alot of cool code
        },
        keydown: function (e) {
            //Alot of cool code
        }
    });
```

However, since they rely on elements that get created after the dom the combined code does not work. So my question is this, is there a way to combine them into the second way and still have them work with classes that are created after the dom. Also is there really any point in combining them? I seem to remember reading some where that its better but I cant remember why or if that was a dream...

Comment: I've asked some days ago an equivalent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604582/multiple-jquery-events-on-one-element-with-different-functions-and-target-select Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/4191657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the selector as the second parameter,  note that using closest static parent is more efficient than using document object.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
         //Alot of cool code
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
         //Alot of cool code
    },
    click: function (e) {
        //Alot of cool code
    },
    keydown: function (e) {
        //Alot of cool code
    }
}, '.profile li');
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. Is there any benefit to doing it like this vs doing it as all separate functions?

Comment: @cKendrick You are welcome, this makes your code cleaner but there is no main difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked some days ago an equivalent [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604582/multiple-jquery-events-on-one-element-with-different-functions-and-target-select).

My answer is quite simple, use my workaround-function, [gist](https://gist.github.com/4191657).

So you can simply use it like this:

```
$(document).act(
    ['mouseenter', 'selector1', function() {}],
    ['mouseleave', 'selector2', function() {}],
    ['mousedown', 'selector3', function() {}],
    ['mouseup', 'selector4', function() {}]
);
```

Or even simple, without my script:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {},
    mousedown: function() {},
    mouseup: function() {}
}, "selector");
```

However, this assumes that you want to use the same selector for all of those events.

Answer (score 0):

If `.profile` are static elements, try this:

```
$('.profile').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
             //Alot of cool code
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
             //Alot of cool code
        },
        click: function (e) {
            //Alot of cool code
        },
        keydown: function (e) {
            //Alot of cool code
        }
    },'li');​​​​
```